# Вектор. Как вместо значения получить индекс

Tags: c++, vector

Было задание сделать бинарный поиск, и если число найдено - вернуть индекс, а если нет, то -1.
Не хотелось бы перебирать через какой-нибудь цикл. Можно ли как-то получить индекс.

```
class Solution 
{
public:
    int search(vector<int>& nums, int target) 
    {
        int low = nums[0];
        int high = nums[nums.size() - 1];
        int mid = (low + high) / 2 ;
      
    while(low != high || mid != target)
     {
     
 
        if (mid < target)
        {
            low = mid + 1;
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
        }
        if (mid > target) 
        {
            high = mid - 1;
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            int *ptr = &nums[mid];
            int *front = &nums[0];
            return (*ptr - *front); 
            
        }
     
    }
             
         return -1;
    }
};
```

Comment: Не хотелось бы спрашивать банальность, но вроде задача не очень сложная... А что Вы пробовали делать?

Comment: Думал может как-нибудь через арифметику указателей можно, но что-то видимо нет.

Comment: `ptr-front`  - через арифметику указателей. Но логичнее просто вернуть mid.

Comment: Или я чего-то не понимаю, или очень странный код.... А что, если в векторе, содержащем пять элементов, первый будет 0, последний 50, а ищем 25? Что вернет функция?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того и написаны стандартные алгоритмы, чтобы мы не возились с циклами. Для вашего случая есть `std::lower_bound`, который как раз выполняет бинарный поиск и возвращает итератор. Реализация вашей функции примет примитивный вид:

```
int search(const std::vector<int>& nums, const int target)
{   
    auto It =
    std::lower_bound(nums.begin(), nums.end(), target);
    return It != nums.end() ? (It - nums.begin()) : -1;    
}
```

Тут, как и полагается, я указал,  что аргументы только для чтения.

Comment: Хотя это все и верно, но так ТС ничему не научится (не зря же ему дали *задание* написать **самому** двоичный поиск)

Comment: @avp,  навряд ли другим пользователям  интересно какое задание, тут важнее суть вопроса _ как решить не перебирая какие нибудь циклы....